# Difficulty stabilizing a system using sisotool on Matlab

Tags: dc-dc-converter, transfer-function, matlab, controller, state-space

I am trying to design a controller for a synchronous buck converter by using the siso tool on Matlab. 
The inductance value is 1.28mH, the filter capacitance is at 4.8uF and the load is a 240Ohm resistor. The maximum input voltage is 800 V and the switching frequency is 75Khz.

I am targeting a 7.5Khz bandwidth for my controller and a reasonable rise time with an overshoot of less than 20%. I am only changing the reference values and am trying to look at how the voltage tracks it. So, I am making a controller for my reference to output.

```
Vinmax = 800;
fsw = 75e+3;
L = 1.288e-03;
C = 4.831e-06;
R = 240;
H = tf(1,[L*C,L/R,1]);
plant = H*Vinmax;

%launch the sisotool for tuning the controller
sisotool(plant)
```

I have been trying for a very long time to stabilize the plant for the required specs and have been very unsuccessful. I would be grateful if anyone could comment on how to proceed further and design a controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want a second order controller without overshoot. The equation for the second order system should be on the mold of,
$$H(s) =\frac{H_0}{\left(\dfrac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 +2 \dfrac{\zeta}{\omega_0} s + 1} = \frac{V_{in_{max}}}{LCs^2+\dfrac{L}{R}s+1},$$
Where, \$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$ and \$\zeta=\frac{\sqrt{L}}{2R\sqrt{C}}\$.

By looking at [the overshoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_(signal)) formula for second order systems you will see that you want it to have 
$$\zeta = 0.$$

But, to have it as such you would have to have \$L=0\$, which you cannot for the system to work. Now, to get within the 20% overshoot that you want you can use the formula (on the wikipedia link) and figure out how big \$\zeta\$ can be.

With the following system/controller:

```
feedback(series(pid(1,0.001,0.000005),plant),1)
```

[image: Block diagram for the negative feedback with PID controller]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO7OgX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I got the following result,

[image: Bode plot showing stability]

[image: Step response showing overshoot of less then 20%]